# How to avoid loops for sparse Matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, sparse-matrix

I am having problem with 3 loops in Python. 
**The purpose of this code** is to calculate sparse matrix according to number of (x) unknown values of **DATA**. Here, x number is 13 , which means unrepeated values of DATA :**(0, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27)**. Then, len(DATA) is 4 that indicates rows number of A_sparse matrix. Then, I create sparse zero matrix with shape(4,13). Then, I take **portion** value to **A_sparse** if **x** is equal to unknown value.

**Question**

- This code work properly, but with loops!!! I should remove loops, but
  how?

Here, I put example below:

**Inputs:**

- DATA - indicates index; [[24, 20, 21, 22, 23], [24, 25, 26, 27], [25, 26, 27, 23], [0, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20]]
- PORTION - [[ 1.16950604,  0.08724138,  1.5326188 ,  1.5326188 ,  0.74587448], 
            [ 0.44409055,  1.51394507,  1.51394507,  0.95883188], 
            [ 0.77097384,  1.77917041,  0.14615981,  0.185952  ], 
            [ 0.93,  1.5 ,  1.5 ,  1.5 ,  1.5 ,  0.07]]

**Output:**
 - A_sparse - Sparse matrix;

```
def get_sparse(DATA, PORTION):

    x = np.unique( flatten(DATA) )
    A = np.zeros((len(DATA), len(x)))

    for i in range(len(DATA)):
        for m1,m2 in enumerate(DATA[i]):
            for j,k in enumerate(x):
                    if float(m2) == float(k):
                            A[i][j] = PORTION[i][m1]
    return A


>>> get_sparse(DATA, PORTION)
array([[ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
     0.08724138,  1.5326188 ,  1.5326188 ,  0.74587448,  1.16950604,
     0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
   [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
     0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.44409055,
     1.51394507,  1.51394507,  0.95883188],
   [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
     0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.185952  ,  0.        ,
     0.77097384,  1.77917041,  0.14615981],
   [ 0.93      ,  1.5       ,  1.5       ,  1.5       ,  1.5       ,
     0.07      ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
     0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ]])
```

I do often not prefer using loops when I use Python,so, I wanted to remove loops to make this code shorter and faster.
Any answer would be appreciated!

Comment: Try [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html) that's SciPy sparse matrix package.

Comment: Kobi, thanks, I looked through it! But, I am not familiar with Scipy sparse matrix tools, I only know in mathematics, but I cannt really convert it to my above mentioned problem..? How can I do that??

Comment: I added a `sparse` example to my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the irregular lists of lists nature of DATA and PORTION, a numpy vectorization of this problem is not obvious.  However, it helps me to visualize the constructor if I print `get_sparse(DATA, DATA)`:

```
[[ 0  0  0  0  0 20 21 22 23 24  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 24 25 26 27]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 23  0 25 26 27]
 [ 0  4  8 12 16 20  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]]
```

Those look like regular column numbers, except the first ones step by 4.  This version of your function builds a (4,28) array, and then trims out the `zero` columns.

```
def get_sparse(DATA, PORTION):
    x = np.unique(itertools.chain(*DATA) )
    A = np.zeros((len(DATA), max(x)+1))
    for a, d, p in zip(A, DATA, PORTION):
        a[d] = p
    return A[:,x]
```

To use sparse matrices, try:

```
from scipy import sparse
A = sparse.lil_matrix((4,28))
A.data = PORTION
A.rows = DATA
```

Your DATA and PORTION lists of lists exactly match the internal format of the `lil_matrix` type.  Once constructed `A` can be transformed into one of the other sparse types for math or slicing.  `A.toarray()` gives the full 'dense' form.